# How does wordpress do to make functions.php available withouut includes?

Tags: php, wordpress

It may be a silly question, but I cant understand how I can access every function (from functions.php for example) in WordPress without any `include` or `require` calls, I know if I want to create a new script I can simply require `wp-load.php` from that particular script, just dont understand why this is isn't needed in other template files.

Comment: It has to be called from somewhere. It's probably within the header file or something similar

Comment: It maybe doing autoloading, but scan through wp-load, it must be loading other files in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress does that automatically.  Whenever there is a functions.php file for the active theme, WP will load it for you.  The magic happens in wp-settings.php, specifically among the following lines:

```
if ( ! defined( 'WP_INSTALLING' ) || 'wp-activate.php' === $pagenow ) {
    if ( TEMPLATEPATH !== STYLESHEETPATH && file_exists( STYLESHEETPATH . '/functions.php' ) )
        include( STYLESHEETPATH . '/functions.php' );
    if ( file_exists( TEMPLATEPATH . '/functions.php' ) )
        include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/functions.php' );
}
```